# Should questions about bash's vi mode be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions about bash's [vi mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-vi-Mode.html) (or [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC22) in general) be on-topic?

Comment: This is a special case of [What is considered to be vi?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi). I'm not voting to close as a duplicate right away because there may be a good reason to discuss it separately.

Comment: What is vim mode in bash?

Comment: I THINK I have seen that before in action, but not absolutely sure... I will research it some more. But See that it only provides the absolute basic of vi commands, it makes sense for it to NOT be on topic.

Comment: @onebree `set -o vi` will make bash’s readline behave similarly to vi—effectively, you can hit escape and move around to edit your command using vi commands.

Answer (score 9):

No:

1. It's not an editor
2. It's not "compatible" with vi; it only implements a (very) small subset.

Also see:
[What is considered to be vi?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi).

We should *focus* the site on vi-editors, bringing in the entire kittenkaboodle that has keybinds vaguely reminiscent of vi and we'll basically be superuser or unix.se

Comment: Nobody knows what will be next, but we can only prepare for [the worst](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1219/852) ;)

Comment: If memory serves, the expression is « kit and kaboodle »

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `readline` and `zle` are both stand alone special purpose text editors. Their special purpose is `line editting`.

This falls in scope of the guidelines proposed here:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. When I wrote the top-posted answer on this question the site was very new, and restricting the scope was a good idea (it's easy to expand a scope later on, not so easy to narrow it). I think expanding it to vi-mode in shells probably makes sense now that the site is more firmly established, and there is probably a significant overlap in expertise.

Comment: I think expanding the scope for this is something that's probably best done with another meta question. I've been intending to [write an answer to this one](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/51) for a while, proposing just that (although I don't think that vi-like shortcuts in browsers should be on-topic). I just haven't found the time yet :-(

Answer (score 5):

I my opinion we should not allow questions about Vi mode in Bash (or other programs). Bash is not Vi(m). And a lot of programs do have some kind of Vi(m) mode. If we allow questions about Vi mode in bash, we should also allow questions about those programs.

Answer (score 3):

While my initial impression is to agree that this should be a "no", I also can't imagine that the subset of "all possible readline vi-mode" questions would be large enough to detract from this site in any way.

After thinking about it more (this was a complete reversal in an edit; if you read my answer before, yes, I'm indecisive) I think that these questions *should* be on topic — or at least should be considered on an individual basis. Having more questions about "vim-like" programs and plugins will only make this a richer community, and a more helpful niche of the internet.