# Should we allow evil questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

In an answer to a related question about vi-mode in bash, an answerer [asked](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/57/852) what would be next. Given that the operating system that shall not be named (the one that swaps constantly, even given 8 MB of ram) has been reported as being used as an editor and supports a plugin called *[evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil)* featuring a vi-like input scheme, is it on-topic here?

Comment: Also discussed at the emacs.SE site: http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/q/6/6543

Comment: @Carpetsmoker You say it's a duplicate, yet your answer directly contradicts the consensus there.

Comment: @Doorknob Oh? In what way? I just elaborated on my 3rd "suggestion", and even derobert's answer really says the same thing, even if he doesn't make it a 'rule'... In any case, I think it's more useful to have a *single* question about this, and not a gazillion about every possible combination *unless* there's a good reason to (for example, the `bvi` question, which is more complicated).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Hmm. I don't see anything about having to be a stand-alone program in derobert's answer (in fact, it specifically states that this does *not* have to be the case). Perhaps the question should be more specific (or the answers should be more complex) — evil questions are on topic *if and only if* they are directly related to the vi-like behavior ("directly related" is still a term that needs to be expanded upon).

Comment: @Doorknob From derobert's answer: *"If you want to know why Visual Studio is giving some weird error message when you try to save a file, that's for Stack Overflow or Super User. If you want to know the keys to hit to quickly change all the occurrences of "foo" to "bar" in the brace-delimited block your cursor is in, that's on-topic."* ... This is *pretty much* the same thing...

Comment: @Doorknob In any case, my point in marking this are a duplicate is that my answer below could be copied/pasted in the "What is considered to be vi?" question with minor modifications (which I will do later), this would keep the discussion about it *in one place*... I don't see any reason why we need to have a discussion about evil, as such (except maybe that questions about it have a good home already at Emacs.SE)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Alright, fair point; that makes sense. I've added my duplicate vote as well.

Answer (score 9):

I think that most, if not all, questions about [evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6ucZsJQxbQ) should be asked at the Emacs.SE site. Not because I don't like Emacs, but because those questions will almost certainly get better answers there.

There is a [broad consensus](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/guidelines-for-external-packages-in-answers) that questions about [evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6ucZsJQxbQ) are on-topic on the Emacs site, and [there are already 18 of them](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil?sort=votes&pageSize=15). Most seem to have good answers.

If you look over the questions, and especially the answers, then you will see that it requires **Emacs expertise** to give those answers, and **not** vi expertise. [Do you know what these answers do](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/608/evil-map-keybindings-the-vim-way)? I certainly don't. I don't even understand the question, since it assumes you know what <kbd>M-.</kbd> does in Emacs.
After all, [evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6ucZsJQxbQ) is really just a bunch of key mappings and commands built on top of Emacs.

This is why I put this restriction in [my answer for 'What is considered to be vi?'](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8/51):

> It must be a stand-alone program; so a plugin for Visual Studio that gives you vi-like keys doesn't count.

Because *most*, if not all, questions will be about the underlying platform (Visual studio, Emacs, and such), and will require expertise in *that* platform to answer.

**This doesn't mean you can't ask questions if you're using [evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6ucZsJQxbQ)**. I have never used it, but I would suspect that many vi-questions on this site already work. But these questions are not really about [evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6ucZsJQxbQ), *as such*.

Comment: And although we have slightly different criteria, I think we come to the same conclusion. That elisp is definitely not "vi-like behavior" (to quote from my answer on the other question).

Answer (score 1):

Let's see; does it meet the [criteria we set earlier](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/88)?

- Its main purpose is a text-editor; anything other that has the vi user interface paradigm (as so far as one exists) is far too broad a scope. — Check.
- It must be mostly compatible with the original vi for all basic operations; where mostly is not precisely defined. — Check.

So, yes, I don't see why evil shouldn't be on-topic.