# Is nvi (BSD variant of vi) on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked a question about how to use the contents of a register in an `ex` command in nvi [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19322/nvi-use-contents-of-register-in-ex-command) and a discussion ensued about whether `nvi` is on topic. Prior to asking the question, I assumed that it was on topic because a) `vi` is in the name of the site and `b`) a tag for `nvi` already existed (admittedly with few questions).

I was curious so I tried hunting around for related discussion that might shed some light on the on-topicness of `nvi`. [This question and its answers](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi) would suggest yes because `nvi` is a `vi`-like text editor. Also, there are many shared features that `vim` and `nvi` both have because of their `vi` heritage.

A comment on a different question, proposes a different test though: [*whether the community collectively has sufficient expertise in the software to answer questions about it*](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/a-suggestion-to-broaden-the-sites-scope-to-things-using-vi-keybinding#comment1105_1464). This would make a strong argument against defining questions about `nvi` to be on-topic. The documentation on it is very sparse because the editor is not popular. User-oriented documentation or information about customization is also sparse. [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.editors/5HCzKBKofxo) was the most useful discussion I could find anywhere before asking my question. The `nvi` source code is also hard to read, which I guess is another barrier to answering questions about it.

Comment: Yes, it's on-topic.

Comment: If it’s not on topic we need to change the name of the site.

Comment: @Rich meta-meta-question: how did you link to the comment?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet The time of the comment (after the name) is a permalink to it.

Answer (score 1):

nvi is a compatible re-implementation of the original vi (chiefly for license reasons). It meets all the criteria in 
[What is considered to be vi](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/51), and is thus on-topic.

The confusion in the question's comments were simply because one moderator wasn't familiar with nvi, as it's comparatively obscure (can't know everything right). Sorry for the mix-up.