# Are questions about `bvi` on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[bvi](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a vi-like hex editor. Are questions about `bvi` on-topic?

1. It's an editor
2. I'm not sure how compatible it is, but AFAIK it's *mostly* compatible with `vi`
3. It's a standalone program

So it seems to meet the criteria; but it's also quite different ... Should we make this an exception to the rule?

Also see: 
[What is considered to be vi?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi)

Comment: It seems like this is really just a duplicate of the other question, unless we want to argue about whether `bvi` is "mostly". (Well, I sure don't, as I have never even used it.)

Comment: @derobert the other question is about the general guidelines or rule of thumb; this question is about whether a program meets those guidelines, or is enough of a 'special case' to be included (or excluded) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I would say **yes**. The site says, "If you are familiar with vi, just start the editor and begin to edit!" This, to me, implies that the program is "vi-like" enough that, as a user, I'd expect to find usable information about `bvi` by learning more about `vi`.

That said, perhaps I'm thinking this way because my attitude toward the scope of "vi-knowledge" is apparently more along the lines of "vi is (or at least represents) a user interface that has been adopted for many programs, *some* of them text editors" than "vi is an old text editor." Carpetsmoker's answer to the "What is considered to be vi" question explicitly stated that only *text-editors* are on-topic. My impulse is to disagree, but I have no principled reason for doing so; it's just a knee-jerk reaction.

Answer (score 2):

I would say **no**.

- It's an editor, but you can't edit *text* with it. It's not a *text editor*.
- It's *roughly compatible*, but some things are rather different (for example, ranges work on bytes, not lines). I would say it's not *compatible enough*.