# Are gVim and MacVim interface questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are gVim and MacVim questions related to interface (such as menu, tabs, settings) on topic? Or just plain vim commands?

Related:

- [What is considered to be vi?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi)
- [Are questions about `bvi` on-topic?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/467)

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: It could be OS dependent and I don't know how far they're compatible with vim. See also: [What is considered to be vi?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/7/467).

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of "What is considered to be vi?", since I don't see any reason why this should be a special case (unlike the `bvi` question, which might be).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Agreed. Let's not split this conversation, preferring instead to resolve it under one comprehensive thread that defines which variants are covered under this namesake.