# Are vipe questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Vipe is a Vim command pipe editor](http://pivotallabs.com/vipe-a-vim-command-pipe/) which allows you to run a text editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and edit the data that is being piped between programs.

It's something considered to be on topic?

It's a stand-alone program, allows you to run a text editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and as far as I know it's compatible with original vi operations. Vipe is part of `moreutils` package.

Related:

- [What is considered to be vi?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/467)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker [different vipe](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, vipe is off-topic, just like vipw, sudoedit, etc. It has nothing to do with vi. It's a program that invokes your favorite editor which may or may not be vi.

An issue that is specifically about vipe calling vi, and would not arise if you were calling some other editor, would be on-topic here. But generic questions about vipe are not.