# Can I ask about 'Vim Adventures' here?

Tags: support

I recently asked a question on SO [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287234/can-i-ask-about-vim-adventures-here?noredirect=1#comment161145_287234) asking if I can ask about 'Vim Adventures' here and this is where I was redirected along with [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com). Is this site ok to ask this here?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current consensus based on ["What is considered to vi?"](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi) at the time of this writing would lead me to say "no, you can't."

Vim Adventures is a game, first and foremost. It's a fun tool for learning about vim, but it's main purpose is *not* to be a text editor. Questions about Vim Adventures already have [a home on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-adventures), and I think that is the appropriate place for them to remain.

- If the question is about Vim Adventures to the point where you want to tag it as such, it's probably *also* more about the "gaming" aspects of the program (such as completing a particular level, or locating the ability to unlock a particular key). Thus, Arqade is the better place.
- If the question is about how to use a particular subset of vim's functionality to achieve a desired result (such as move to a particular location in some text using only a certain set of keys), *that's* probably appropriate here, but at that point you've divorced the issue from the implementation sufficiently to not *need* to tag it with [vim-adventures](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-adventures).