# Are questions regarding kakoune text editor allowed here?

Tags: discussion

I am currently trying to get into [kakoune](http://kakoune.org). Even though it is built with influence from vim, but it is not vi descendant in any way or form. Are questions regarding kakoune allowed here?

Comment: I'd say no, as it's pretty different from vi. Also see [What is considered to be vi?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37/51).

Comment: @MartinTournoij based on my understanding of kakounr and the linked answer, I agree—Kakoune doesnt support the posix subset of vi(m), even though it’s paradigm is vi-influenced

Comment: I do agree too. [This page](https://kakoune.org/why-kakoune/why-kakoune.html) shows that a lot of things work differently in Kakoune which makes it pretty much off topic.