# Add a "not about Vi or Vim" close reason

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

In the [close reason](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) mod toolbox almost all custom close reasons are because the question isn't about Vi or Vim. Not sure how much reputation you need to view that, but here's a screenshot:

[image]

I propose we add a custom close reason for this, since it's a fairly common close reason.

---

On the same page it actually lists this twice already, as:

> This question does not appear to be about Vi and Vim family of editors, within the scope defined in the [help center](/help).

Once added as "Community" and once by me in 2017, but neither shows up  I think moderators should probably approve one or the other.

It might be a good idea to tweak the link to /help/on-topic rather than /help, which is a bit clearer:

> This question does not appear to be about Vi and Vim family of editors, within the scope defined in the [help center](/help/on-topic).

Comment: I’d was surprised to discover that “not about Vim” isn’t in the close dialog: it’s frequently used as a close reason. e.g. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37510/v-command-unix-relation-to-vi-or-vim Do moderators use a different list from us regular joes?

Comment: I think that may be the "default reason" if you enter a custom one @Rich; I think that's maybe also why it displays twice 

Comment: I _think_ it is sometimes applied when the community closes a Q and the votes are for different reasons?

Comment: This is a great idea. One thing to point out is [about a year ago the close reason format changed to be more useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584/236364) so we should try to write up the close reason in that format. I don't mind doing the initial draft for it, but it may not be until the weekend.

Comment: Trying to notify as many eyes as I can (@Dom). Since there's an accepted answer, I'll look at setting this up tomorrow; if there are any changes or concerns I'll push back by another 24h each time to let things settle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a very bare bones suggestions for the close reason. I think section 4 could use more fleshing out to explain and guide new users on questions they think may be about Vi or Vim that aren't directly related.

---

1. **Brief description**

   > **Not about Vi or Vim**
2. **Usage guidance**

   > This question does not directly relate to the Vi and Vim family of editors. Consider leaving a comment pointing the asker to the appropriate site if one exists.
3. **Post notice close description**

   > This question was **closed** because it is not directly about the Vi and Vim family of editors. It is not currently accepting answers.  See [the on-topic page](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more info.
4. **Post owner guidance**

   > Your question does not seem to be directly about Vi and Vim family of editors.  If you believe your question is about Vi and Vim family of editors, edit the question to explain how your question directly relates to them.
5. **Privileged user guidance**

   > If you believe the question is directly about Vi and Vim family of editors, help by editing the question to improve it or leave a comment guiding the asker in how they could improve their question.

Comment: Usually, [this post](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi) gets linked to when explaining what is considered on topic here. Not sure if the close reason should link to this directly?

Comment: @Rich there is a character limit to these fields, but it should fit into 3. See the edit.

Comment: The `/on-topic` page contains more or less the same information @Rich; it's also a page mods can edit by the way, so we can improve it if need be. Personally I think that's a better page to link because it's a bit more expansive, but I'm fine with the meta Q too.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I agree.

Comment: updated to point to the on topic page.

Comment: I've edit the close reason; please review/approve

Comment: @D.BenKnoble approved.